# Should I use Datatype.Text for Integer attributes in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, types

(I'm using Asp.net MVC to create a web app.)
For example, suppose I have a class Person in my Model.

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
}
```

If I do not give Age a datatype, in the Razor "Create" & "Edit" methods, I would have to write boilerplate code for each attribute of Person to achieve the display effect I want.
I just want to use `@Html.EditorForModel` (Side Q : is this the right way to do so?), but if I don't have a datatype, the editor would be a `<input type="number">` and has little up and down arrows I don't want to have.

But if I give Age a datatype like this:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name;
    [Datatype(Datatype.Text)]
    public int Age;
}
```

Is there any hidden risk if I give the integer `Age` a Text Datatype?

Comment: Type Casting should always be required in this scenario.

Comment: If you must do this, use a view model, then map to the entity on the server side.

Comment: @Maess : should i use `Datatype.Text` for int in view model ?

Comment: @Maess Yeah, I'm just wondering whether I should do this in a Model.